# A dynamic crud table for auto addition and subtraction

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a dynamic table.

There's an input form. Onsubmit form, inputs are automatically added to a dynamically generated table (using vanilla JS). Numeric contents are automatically added to give total value. On delete row (any), the numeric value of that row should be automatically subtracted from the total.

My only issue is with the subtraction aspect. I've tried several things to get the innerHTML of the cells that contain the numeric value for each deleted row.

```js
var total = 0;

function createCustomerRow() {    
    var Cname = document.getElementById("customer").value,
    Cemail = document.getElementById("email").value,
    Cphone = document.getElementById("phone").value,
    Cbalance = document.getElementById("balance").value,
    Cbalance = parseInt(Cbalance, 10);

    if ( Cname == '' || Cemail == '' || Cphone == '' || Cbalance == '' ) {
        alert("You are required to fill in all the fields");
    } else {
        var newRow = document.getElementById("tableContainer"),
            newCust = newRow.insertRow(tableContainer.length),
            cust = newCust.insertCell(0),
            email = newCust.insertCell(1),
            phone = newCust.insertCell(2),
            balance = newCust.insertCell(3),
            deleCust = newCust.insertCell(4);

        cust.innerHTML = Cname;
        email.innerHTML = Cemail;
        phone.innerHTML = Cphone;
        balance.innerHTML = Cbalance;
        deleCust.innerHTML = '<button id="deleteCust" onclick="deleteCustomer(this)">Delete</button>';
        newCust.style.backgroundColor = " bisque";
        newCust.style.border = "1px solid gray";
        newCust.style.width = "1400px";
        newCust.style.color = "red";
        cust.style.padding = "10px";
        cust.style.borderRight = "1px solid black";
        email.style.padding = "10px";
        email.style.borderRight = "1px solid black";
        phone.style.padding = "10px";
        phone.style.borderRight = "1px solid black";
        balance.style.padding = "10px";
        balance.style.borderRight = "1px solid black";
        cust.style.fontSize = "20px";
        email.style.fontSize = "20px";
        phone.style.fontSize = "20px";
        balance.style.fontSize = "20px";
        
        total += Cbalance;

        document.getElementById("second").innerHTML = total;

        clearInput();
        return false;
    }
}

function clearInput() {
    document.getElementById("customer").value = "";
    document.getElementById("email").value = "";
    document.getElementById("phone").value = "";
    document.getElementById("balance").value = "";
}


function deleteCustomer(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("tableContainer").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```css
body {
 padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;    
    height: auto;
}

table#tableContainer, table#total {
 width: 1400px;
 margin: auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
 padding: 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table#total {
    margin-top: 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 1400px;
}

.first, .second {
    border: 0;
}

.second {
    padding-left: 100px;
}


tr {
 width: 1200px;
}


th {
    width: 200px;
 padding: 10px;
 color: wheat;
 background-color: black;
 text-align: center;
 border: 1px solid burlywood;
}


#custInfo {
    width: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 80px 0px 0px 100px;
    border: 1px solid greenyellow;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

input[type="text"] {
    width: 400px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: red;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
    background-color: bisque;
    color: blueviolet;
}

label, input[type="submit"] {
    margin-left: 30px;
    color: rgb(190, 81, 9);
}

input[type="submit"] {
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
}

#deleteCust {
    color: rgb(190, 81, 9);
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableContainer">
  <tr>
   <th class="display">Customer</th>
   <th class="display">Email</th>
   <th class="display">Phone</th>
   <th class="display">Balance</th>
   <th class="display">Action</th>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="total">
    <tr>
        <th class="first">Total</th>
        <th class="first"></th>
        <th class="first"></th>
        <th class="second" id="second"></th>
        <th class="first"></th>
    </tr>
</table>
    
<div  id="custInfo">
    <label for="customer">Customer</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="customer" name="customer"> <br /><br />
    <label for="email">Email</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email"> <br /><br />
    <label for="phone">Phone</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone"> <br /><br />
    <label for="balance">Balance</label> <br />
    <input type="text" id="balance" name="balance"> <br /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="custSubmit" value="submit" name="custSubmit" onclick="createCustomerRow()">
</div>
```

This is the link to the code on my Github.
https://github.com/layodaniel/crud

Please kindly help out. I'm pretty new to programming. And I have to submit this project already.

Thanks.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. You can [edit] the post and create a working snippet by clicking on the `<>` button in the editor

Comment: Hi bro. I sincerely don't understand you. This is my first time of asking a question on stackoverflow. I just signed up today. I tried writing my code in my initial post but I wasn't allowed to publish it due to some formatting error (as I was alerted). And in relationship to your comment, I can't find any "<> button" in the editor. I had to include the link to the code on my github account for anyone who might want to help out.

Comment: Can I edit and include the code for you?

Comment: Yes, please. I'd really appreciate that. I've been trying to solve this for about a month now.

Comment: @DanielOlatunji The `<>` button is the Stack Snippet button. In the editor toolbar, it's the 7th option. It looks like a piece of paper with the `<>` icon on it (just to the right of the image button), and allows you to add runnable code to your question. This allows us to run the code, see the issues, make changes, etc. But most importantly it removes the reliance on an external resource (like github).

Comment: @DanielOlatunji DONE. If you need to change anything the code snippet then [edit] the post and you'll see in the preview of the question, under the actual snippet you have a link `edit the above snippet` - Click on that link and the code editor will pop for editing

Comment: @Alon Eitan, thanks bro. You're so kind. I really appreciate you.

Comment: @Tyler Roper, thanks. I'm just very new to stackoverflow. I'd try to figure out the way things work here. Thanks so much. I'm grateful.